# Can any stolen military vehicles be insured/garaged?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I got a jeep from the military base to Los Santos Customs. I can bring it inside and install explosives but that's it - can't install a tracker and "own" the vehicle. Are there any military vehicles that can be stolen and have a tracker attached? I know some of the vehicles can be purchased, but I'm not interested in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can through glitches](https://www.google.com/search?q=gta5+military+vehicle+insurance&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&ie=&oe=), but most military vehicles you can't own/insure without purchasing them yourself.